# Daily updating a dataframe in python and applying possible changes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, comparison

I have a dataframe that has connected to a database. The dataframe is updating every day and I want to write code to compare the today's dataframe with the yesterday's dataframe. If there is any changes in today's dataframe then uses that for the rest of code otherwise just stop running the code and exit. I have the following code for that but I do not know what is the best way to save the yesterday's dataframe somewhere to compare it with the today's dataframe OR is there any other efficient way? Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
import os


today_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'date', 'count'])

yesterday_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'date', 'count'])


def is_dataFrames_equal(today_df, yesterday_df):
    if (len(yesterday_df) == len(today_df)):
        # len(yesterday_df) == len(today_df) and there is no changes
        if (today_df['id'] == yesterday_df['id']).all() and (today_df['date'] == yesterday_df['date']).all() and (today_df['count'] == yesterday_df['count']).all():
            return True
        # len(yesterday_df) == len(today_df) and there is changes  
        else:
            return False
    # len(yesterday_df) != len(today_df)
    else:
        return False

if is_dataFrames_equal(today_df, yesterday_df):
    print('no new data found.')
    exit()

# today_df - yesterday_df
diff_df = today_df[~today_df.isin(yesterday_df).all(1)]
    
df = today_df.copy(deep=True)
```

Comment: why not just use the diff_df and if its size is greater than 0, then do a copy else do nothing. You can skip the function you written before

Comment: May I ask you please explain what do you mean by checking its size whether it is greater than 0. Thanks. @https://stackoverflow.com/users/3494754/naveed

Comment: diff_df.size gives you the size of it, means if resulting DF has any rows in it or not

Answer (score 0):

You can save your variables using [pickle](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-python-pickling-example/):

```
import pickle


def save_obj(obj, name):
    os.mkdir(f'obj') if not os.path.exists('obj') else None

    with open(f'obj/{name}.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(obj, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)


def load_obj(name):
    try:
        with open(f'obj/{name}.pkl', 'rb') as f:
            return pickle.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None


today_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'date', 'count'])
today_file_name = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
save_obj(today_df, today_file_name)

yesterday_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'date', 'count'])
yesterday_file_name = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y%m%d")
load_obj(yesterday_file_name)
```